# as3 operator= /(object assign )

Tags: actionscript-3

I know that AS3 does not have pointer or reference. Every object is pass by reference already. (I supposed?)
What should I do if I want to do with pointer? 
e.g. all object point to one target, I only need to change target's value, then all other object will access different value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can effectively get the same behavior by using a helper object to simulate a pointer -- in other words using it to carry the target reference. For instance:

```
public class PseudoPointer
{
   private var obj:Object;
   private var prop:String;

   public function PseudoPointer(obj:Object, prop:String)
   {
      // Point to property with name 'prop' on object 'obj'.
      this.obj  = obj;
      this.prop = prop;
   }

   public function get value():* {
      return obj[prop];
   }

   public function set value(value:*):void {
      obj[prop] = value;
   }        
}
```

Then you could do this -- assume there's a `magicNumber` property on an object named `target`:

```
var numberPtr = new PseudoPointer(target, "magicNumber");

myDynamicObjectA.numberPtr = numberPtr;
myDynamicObjectB.numberPtr = numberPtr;
myDynamicObjectC.numberPtr = numberPtr;
```

Now any object that has a reference to the pseudo-pointer can read and write the target property:

```
numberPtr.value = 42;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function and in which you give it the value and then subsequently assign it to all of those other variables.

Something like below:

```
var objectA:Number;
var objectB:Number;
...

function myFunction(newValue:Number):void
{
objectA = newValue;
objectB = newValue;
...
}
```

Comment: Thank you JRulle :) It's a good way, but not the way I want to have. Because my object could be dynamically add or remove at runtime.  This could be not so flexible. The reason I ask for something like "pointer" in AS3 is that I don't want to do something like your codes. Thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting a variable reference to a function. Then if you update that reference, it would return a different function.

```
var myFunc:Function;

function funcOne():int {
    return 1;
}

function funcTwo():int {
    return 2;
}

function getFunc():Function {
    return myFunc;
}

myFunc = funcOne;

var myObjOne:Object = new Object();
myObjOne.objFunc = getFunc;
var myObjTwo:Object = new Object();
myObjTwo.objFunc = getFunc;

trace(myObjOne.objFunc.call().call());   // 1
trace(myObjTwo.objFunc.call().call());   // 1

myFunc = funcTwo;
trace(myObjOne.objFunc.call().call());   // 2
trace(myObjTwo.objFunc.call().call());   // 2
```

This allows any object to point at a single function and have what that returns be updateable for all of them simultaneously. It's not the prettiest code and it's not as type-safe as if ActionScript had delegates to enforce the signatures of what's set for myFunc, but it is still a pretty flexible model if you get creative with it.

Answer (score 0):

Have those pointers point to something that contains the object or has the object as a property on it.

So

var myArr:Array = [new YourObject()];
var client1:ArrayClient = new ArrayClient();
client1.array = myArr;
var client2:ArrayClient = new ArrayClient();
client2.array = myArr;

myArr[0] = new YourObject();

//client1.array[0]==client2.array[0]==the new object

However, this seems to be a great way to get yourself into a lot of trouble really quickly.  What's the use case?

Comment: Hey Amy, I got confused with "ArrayClient". Is that a customized class?

Comment: Yes.  That is a hypothetical Class that has a reference to an array.